# Почему ставится запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Имеется фраза, объясняющая значение слова *предубеждение*: «П. — имеющееся изначально, заранее, предвзятое (обычно отрицательное) мнение, отношение к кому-либо, чему-либо».

Почему обособлено «заранее»?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Предубеждение —  **имеющееся** изначально, заранее, // **предвзятое** (обычно отрицательное) **мнение, отношение** к кому-либо, чему-либо.*

1) **Объяснение записано не лучшим образом:** большое количество запятых мешает пониманию текста.

Вот, к примеру,  **другой вариант** записи словарной статьи:

ПРЕДУБЕЖДЕНИЕ, -я; ср. Предвзятое, заранее сложившееся отрицательное мнение о ком-, чём-л.

2) Вторая запятая разделяет **однородные** определение ***имеющееся, предвзятое*** мнение, отношение.

Однородные определения обозначают **неравные, но сближенные** в данном тексте понятия. **Предвзятое** мнение — это как раз такое мнение о чем-либо, которое человек **имеет** заранее, еще не ознакомившись с этим предметом.